# MiniMagick Interlace isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I have some custom methods to resize my images using MiniMagick

```
def resize_to_limit(dimensions, degrade = false)
  width, height = dimensions
  MiniMagick::Image.open(current_path).tap do |image|
    image.resize "#{width}x#{height}>"
    image.combine_options do |cmd|
      if degrade
        cmd.quality 50
      end
      cmd.alpha 'remove'
      cmd.auto_orient
      cmd.interlace 'plane'
    end
    image.format('jpg')
    image.write current_path
  end
end
```

When I check the resulting image using `identify` the `Interlace` is still `None`. Not sure if the library changed the input value, but I have tried both *Plane* and *plane*.

Comment: It's possible that writing the file on top of itself is causing trouble. Have you tried writing to a different output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to convert an image using the [Metal interface](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick#Appending):

```
require 'mini_magick'

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << "input.jpg"
  convert << "-interlace plane"
  convert << "output.jpg"
end
```

That should amount to the same thing as:

```
$ convert input.jpg -interlace plane output.jpg
```

In fact that command works as expected:

```
$ magick identify -verbose input.jpg output.jpg | grep Interlace
  Interlace: None
  Interlace: JPEG
```

You can see what commands your code is issuing by turning on debugging:

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true
end
```

When I run your code with debugging on, I get a bunch of commands that are working on temp files:

```
MiniMagick.debug is deprecated and will be removed in MiniMagick 5. Use `MiniMagick.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` instead.
D, [2017-05-17T23:30:28.456080 #12301] DEBUG -- : [0.01s] identify /var/folders/dh/_zgl_f_s0t7b4wk9j27cpny80000gp/T/mini_magick20170517-12301-17vo4b8.jpg
D, [2017-05-17T23:30:28.468335 #12301] DEBUG -- : [0.01s] mogrify -resize 500x500> /var/folders/dh/_zgl_f_s0t7b4wk9j27cpny80000gp/T/mini_magick20170517-12301-17vo4b8.jpg
D, [2017-05-17T23:30:28.481606 #12301] DEBUG -- : [0.01s] mogrify -alpha remove -auto-orient -interlace plane /var/folders/dh/_zgl_f_s0t7b4wk9j27cpny80000gp/T/mini_magick20170517-12301-17vo4b8.jpg
D, [2017-05-17T23:30:28.493634 #12301] DEBUG -- : [0.01s] convert /var/folders/dh/_zgl_f_s0t7b4wk9j27cpny80000gp/T/mini_magick20170517-12301-17vo4b8.jpg[0] /var/folders/dh/_zgl_f_s0t7b4wk9j27cpny80000gp/T/mini_magick20170517-12301-hks8tq.jpg
```

One thing I can't help notice [in the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick#Usage) is the line:

> On the other hand, if we want the original image to actually *get* modified, we can use `MiniMagick::Image.new`.

So maybe try `new` instead of `open`. And then watch the debugging output to see if the commands make sense.

It seems maybe your code is overcomplicated? Also from [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick#Combine_options):

> As a handy shortcut, `MiniMagick::Image.new` also accepts an optional block which is used to `combine_options`.

So maybe you don't need the explicit call to `combine_options` if using `new`.

Comment: Logging out the commands showed me that I needed to move the call to `format` earlier in the method. During format it was wiping the interlace settings.

Comment: @CWitty: Ah! That makes  sense. Glad the logging helped.